# Comparing Now.js and Socketstream scalability for a MMO

Tags: node.js, scalability, websocket

If I am to build a real-time MMO, multi-room based, non-persistent world, which  offers the best vertical scalability [consider mainly the number of players served on same machine, and ram footprint]?

Are [Socketstream](https://github.com/socketstream/socketstream) and [Now.js](http://nowjs.org/) ready to use new Node.js 0.6 [Cluster](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.0/api/cluster.html) module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to custom code a solution using the v0.6.x clustering. It came out very recently and besides being very basic, has not had time to be baked into any libraries yet.

I would suggest you look at http://learnboost.github.com/cluster/
It won't work with v0.6.x as far as I'm aware, but according to this issue https://github.com/LearnBoost/cluster/issues/168
Tj is "on it".